# BLS signature verification?

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, taproot, boneh-lynn-shacham-signatures

Is it possible to perform BLS signature verification with upcoming Taproot/Tapscript proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only Schnorr signatures are supported.